# How to tell ESLint about the Svelte Kit $lib folder?

Tags: eslint, svelte, sveltekit

I use Svelte Kit with ESLint, and my `.eslintrc.json` includes the `svelte3` plugin.
Still, ESLint raises errors on all imports from the `$lib` folder, which points to `src/lib`, for example:

```
3:23  error  Unable to resolve path to module '$lib/Glossary.svelte'   import/no-unresolved
```

The error is detected in this import section:

```js
<script>
    import Glossary from '$lib/Glossary.svelte';
</script>
```

It seems as if ESLint is unable to resolve `$lib` to `src/lib`, which is defined in svelte.config.js. How can I tell ESLint to expand `$lib` to `src/lib`?

P.S.: As suggested by @BenMcCann, I created an issue at https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1560.

Comment: eslint is added when you setup a new project. If it's broken by default then that sounds worthy of filing a bug https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues

Comment: @BenMcCann: I carried over my .eslintrc from another project but your comment leads me to investigate the default ESLint configuration from the SvelteKit project setup.

Comment: @BenMcCann: I first made the mistake of copying the configuration files from  github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues, where the issue still exists, then I created a new SvelteKit app as described on the SvelteKit homepage, where the opposite is true: eslint never warns me about any import, even if it does not exist and breaks later at `npm run dev`. Also, `npm run lint` does not show eslint output. I will create an issue.